# existence of irreducible polynomial of degree 10 over finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Prove that there exists an irreducible polynomial of degree 10 over the the field of 25 elements.

I know that the multiplicative group of non-zero elements of any finite field is cyclic. So how can I proceed my work? Thanks!

Comment: Conceptually? We know that there exists a field with $\;5^{20}\;$ elements, namely $\;\Bbb F_{5^{20}}\;$ , and since $\;2\mid 20\;$ we get that $\;\Bbb F_{5^2}\;$ is a subfield of it, and in fact $\;\dim_{\Bbb F_{5^2}}\Bbb F_{5^{20}}=10\;$. But **also** $\;\Bbb F_{5^{20}}\cong\Bbb F_{5^2}[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle\;$ , with $\;f(x)\;$ irreducible of degree $\;10\;$ ...

Comment: @Joanpemo: Proving the existence of this field doesn't require proving there exists an irreducible polynomial of degree $10$?

Comment: @Bernard but the existence of the field $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ can be shown alternatively as being the splitting field of $f(t)=t^{p^{n}}-t$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$, right? That would avoid the circular argument.

Comment: @Bernard In fact it requires the existence of an irreducible pol. of degree $\;20\;$ in $\;\Bbb F_5[x]\;$ . It can also be done with the help of some little stuff from Fields extensions and Galois theory.

Comment: AH...exactly what @user314159 just wrote a few second ago!

Comment: @user3144159: Yes, that's the standard proof, but it requires showing $t^{p^n}-t$ is the product of all irreducible polynomials of degree $d$ for *all* divisors $d$ of $n$. As the question is very specific, I wonder if the O.P. is not asked to *produce* a concrete polynomial of degree $10$.